# Best way to access the full Android internal storage directory tree from an Ubuntu pc

Tags: linux, file-management

### Background

I am trying to free up memory from my phone that is becoming more and more unusable, as it reports only ~600MB free memory out of 16,0GB; but deleting cache files, moving images/videos to my PC, and moving apps to the SD card didn't help much.

When trying to manage the issue from the phone, I find an inconsistent memory count, in that the Memory Management utility reports a total memory usage less than 11 GB (6.5 Firmware, 3.5GB Apps, 0.9GB other, 34MB cache, 21MB images). So where/what are the missing 5GB?

### Attempts to a solution

One approach is to search for apps like in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141689/effective-storage-ridiculously-small-since-marshmallow-update) (but this guy had no much luck, one answer after one year).

So I thought I could understand myself the situation better, and hopefully reach out the root cause, by accessing the phone files directly from Ubuntu (assuming that Android should be, if not a relative or a good friend, at least collaborative with Linux), but attempting to do so I am very much confused when Linux reports only 1,1 GB being used (so I would expect the free memory to be 14.9GB!).

Therefore I understand that by the MTP protocol (that, I read here, is Microsoft, so no wonder it makes things difficult to Linux) I cannot access all files of my android phone "internal memory". And, by the way, PTP accesses even less files!

Additional data:

- the phone is a Huawei P8 2017 Lite (likely I will soon need to the same on a Honor 8 too)
- Android version is 7.0
- Ubuntu is 16.04 (4.15.0-39-generic)

### Other Searches

Of course I understand that such a need must be widespread, and searched for similar questions, and found [a lot around](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66385/how-to-transfer-files-from-an-android-phone-to-a-ubuntu-pc-by-using-a-usb-cable) speaking of MTP, PTP, ADB, AirDroid, even WiFi access, bust most of them seem to me outdated (2012/2015).

[Here too](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/best-file-managers-for-android/), one can find some advice, but it just seems one out of hundreds of similar webpages that are usually too commercial to be true, and one must try dozen apps before finding a suitable one, or ultimately giving up after having exhausted all available time.

So **I am looking for updated information about a (reasonably simple) method to mount the Android filesystem from my Ubuntu pc, and see all files** (particularly those taking all that precious room, to eventually delete them).

Even if it doesn't exist (hope it does) and/or **there are better approaches** (including those that I have already discarded) that could help to solve my problem, I would be glad to read some pointers to.

Comment: I'm quite happy using [adbfs](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless/), which runs as FUSE mount. Much easier and much more reliable than the other candidates you've named. But unless the ADB daemon on your device runs in root (aka "insecure") mode, which it usually does not, there will still be areas inaccessible to you.